# Drawing application with resize when orientation is changed

Tags: android, canvas, rotation, drawing

I'm sorry to disturb, but at this point, i'm really stuck.
I'm trying to make an activity to draw on a picture. But i've no idea how to handle the rotation of the device.

If i change the bitmap with createScaledBitmap, that works but the draws are not in the right place. (The bitmap is bigger and added space)

I need to stretch the bitmap for the new size (in a way that draws are on the right place on the picture).

Everytime my configuration change, i do that :

```
snapshotCanvas.mTempBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(snapshotCanvas.mOriginalBitmap.copy(snapshotCanvas.mOriginalBitmap.getConfig(), true), drawView1.getWidth(), drawView1.getHeight(), false);
snapshotCanvas.mCanvas.setBitmap(snapshotCanvas.mTempBitmap);
snapshotCanvas.mCanvas.scale((float) snapshotCanvas.mCanvas.getWidth() / drawView.getWidth(),
            (float) snapshotCanvas.mCanvas.getHeight() / drawView.getHeight());
```

I tried many things but i got terribly lost.

Thanks in advance.